# Compute a random specifed day to add a days span

Tags: bash

I could compute current day + 28 days with

```
$ date -d '28 days'
Fri 13 Sep 2019 11:32:38 PM CST
```

How could compute a random specified day to add 28 days, saying

date -d "2019-8-8 + 28 days"

Comment: Create a random number and add this number and 28 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `shuf` - generate random permutations

You can use `shuf` for this as follows:

```bsh
date -d "$(shuf -n1 -i0-2019)-$(shuf -n1 -i1-12)-$(shuf -n1 -i1-31) + 28 days"
```

E.g. `shuf -n1 -i0-2019` outputs `1` number from a list of the numbers from `0` to `2019`, so it gives you a random year in this range. The same is done for month (`1-12`) and day(`1-31`). This approach has one problem: As e.g. “2019-2-31” is not a valid date `date` will fail with an error:

```bsh
date: invalid date ‘2019-2-31’
```

### A workaround loop

You can work around that with a loop that is only exited when the command succeeded and suppress the error messages (by redirecting stderr to `/dev/null`):

```bsh
while :; do
  if date -d "$(shuf -n1 -i0-2019)-$(shuf -n1 -i1-12)-$(shuf -n1 -i1-31) + 28 days"; then
    break
  fi
done 2>/dev/null
```

#### Example run

```
$ while :;do if date -d "$(shuf -n1 -i0-2019)-$(shuf -n1 -i1-12)-$(shuf -n1 -i1-31)+28days";then break;fi;done 2>/dev/null
Tue Nov 19 00:00:00 CET 1946
```

### A loop for multiple dates

If you want to create a number of these random dates, change the loop as follows:

```bsh
i=0
while ((i<3)); do
  if date -d "$(shuf -n1 -i0-2019)-$(shuf -n1 -i1-12)-$(shuf -n1 -i31-31) + 28 days"; then
    ((i++))
  fi
done 2>/dev/null
```

The number in line 2, here I used `3`, is the number of dates to output.

#### Example run

```
$ i=0;while ((i<3));do if date -d "$(shuf -n1 -i0-2019)-$(shuf -n1 -i1-12)-$(shuf -n1 -i31-31)+28days";then ((i++));fi;done 2>/dev/null
Sat Nov 28 00:00:00 LMT 0572
Wed Apr 28 00:00:00 LMT 0771
Sun Nov 28 00:00:00 LMT 0917
```